# Ques on why ma’mum read “Barik Lana Fi Shahri Ramadan”aloud after fard solah?

Tags: salat

In Ramadhan when Imam makes a long doa after any fard solah, when it comes to “Barik Lana Fi Shahri Ramadan” the jemaah will read aloud 3 times. Why?

Comment: You should ask them since it isn't a sunnah of the prophet!